# Process variables later in PHP

Tags: php, variables

```
$dir    = './';
$files1 = scandir($dir, 1);
$totalSize = 0;
foreach ($files1 as $fileName)
    $totalSize += filesize($fileName);

echo "TOTAL FILE SIZE:". $totalSize /1024 /1024 ."<br /><br />";

foreach ($files1 as $fileName)
    echo $fileName "<br />";
```

I have a sample code here, I wanna reduce this to just 1 foreach loop and I wanna print my totalSize above, how is this possible? I was thinking if there is any way to "process my $totalSize later"

What I wanted to achieve is something like this:

```
//I WANT THIS TO GET THE VALUE BELOW
echo "TOTAL FILE SIZE:". $totalSize /1024 /1024 ."<br /><br />";

foreach ($files1 as $fileName)
{
    echo $fileName "<br />";
    $totalSize += filesize($fileName);
}
```

Omg stupid me, I was thinking too much about making this possible and forgotten about simple techniques. Thanks to the people who helped me answer this question!

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
$output = "";

foreach ($files1 as $fileName)
{
    $output .= $fileName . "<br />";
    $totalSize += filesize($fileName);
}

echo "TOTAL FILE SIZE:". $totalSize /1024 /1024 ."<br /><br />";

echo $output;
```

You cant echo something that is not set first. In my code example, you have one loop where it stores the filenames in a variable, and echos it later.